# Conditional Formatting in Excel via a different worksheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I've been trying to figure out how to make a cell bold and color red based on conditions **entirely in a different worksheet**. For example, I'd like `Sheet1!A1` to be bold and red when `Sheet2!A1 = Sheet2!$A7`. I have a pretty big array of numbers, so copying Sheet 2 into Sheet 1 isn't my ideal solution, although I will if I absolutely must.

I've tried using IF statements with `cell("address")` and the like, but nothing really worked (attempting to mimic things like Cell Value = xx). Is this not the proper way to find a cell's address? Or are there better suited ways of calling a cell's address more applicable here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an OR statement, e.g.

```
=OR(Sheet2!A1=Sheet2!$A7)
```

I haven't tested this, but I use OR or AND statements often in these types of situations. It really doesn't matter if you use OR or AND, but for single-statement logic I prefer OR. It's just a preference.

Comment: Can you explain what function the OR (or AND) serves?

Comment: This worked great and is much simpler than what I was attempting. Thanks! (I think the OR serves as a simple logical test.)

Comment: @fixer1234, OR (or AND) just gives you a logic test that evaluates to true or false, neither requires more than one argument, and all Conditional Format needs is an equation that evaluates to False or Not False (True = Not False).

Comment: You don't need the function for that.  Just =(Sheet2!A1=Sheet2!$A7) will do it.

Comment: Yup! You're absolutely right, @fixer1234.